# PHP Datetime with MySQL datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to ask about changing a datetime value of PHP with datetime value from MySQL data.

I have try to do this at PHP:

```
$sitgl = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(2012-01-12));
$sijam = date('H:i:s', strtotime(13:00:00));
$awal = $sitgl.' '.$sijam;
$awal2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($awal));
$debrangkat = strtotime($awal2);
```

And I'm trying to convert same datetime at MySQL like this (convert it to seconds):

```
SELECT date_start_book, time_start_book, (TO_DAYS(CAST(date_start_book AS DATE))*86400) + TIME_TO_SEC(CAST(time_start_book AS TIME)) FROM `t_request_queue` WHERE `request_id` = '1301-0087'
```

which is date_start_book value is 2012-01-12 and time_start_book value is 13:00:00

My question is: why the PHP code return value : 1357970400  but the MySQL value return 63525214800 ?

what must I do to make both of value is same? Is strtotime() not return a seconds or why?

Comment: That PHP code hurts my brain

Comment: just use `MySQL DateTime functions`

Comment: strtotime('2012-01-12 13:00:00');is enough

Comment: actually I'm getting $sitgl from a row from database which is [date_start_book], I don't want to confusing my question so I'm changing them to the value of that rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I change the PHP to datetime and at query I'm using ADD_DAYS to add a date with a seconds then I compare it with the PHP datetime result.

So many thanks to all contributor.

Answer (score 2):

First of all as others have suggested that php code is really hurting brain. You could make that Unix Timestamp in just one line.  But to answer your real question. MYSQL TO_DAYS works different than PHP UNIX Timestamp

According to [MySQL Website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

```
Given a date date, returns a day number (the number of days since year 0). 
mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS(950501);
        -> 728779
mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS('2007-10-07');
        -> 733321

 TO_DAYS() is not intended for use with values that precede the advent of the Gregorian calendar (1582), because it does not take into account the days that were lost when the calendar was changed. For dates before 1582 (and possibly a later year in other locales), results from this function are not reliable
```

And according to [PHP Website](http://us.php.net/time) **timestamp** is

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

And hence the difference in two values. Their starting point is way too distant from each other. MySQL starts from year 0 and PHP starts from year 1970.

**Suggestion**

I would suggest you save php's timestamp in mysql rather than a formatted date time. This will help you stay consistent and allow you to perform any date or time comparisons easily.